# How to disable ESLint from adding items into useEffect's array of watchers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, eslint, tslint

I am using firebase firestore real-time with React and placed my listener inside a `useEffect`.

Here's the code

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsub = db.collection('messages')
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            // Check if it's existing in messages
            const index = messages.findIndex(i => i.id === doc.id)

            if (index === -1) {
                const newMessage = {
                    id: doc.id,
                    ...doc.data()
                }
                setMessages([newMessage, ...messages])
            }
        });
    });

    return () => unsub()
}, [])
```

Every time I try to save the file, it adds the `messages` state inside the useEffect array

```
useEffect(() => {
    // code
}, [messages])
```

It's getting annoying and because of this behavior, it keeps on restarting the listener and causing me to get duplicate data, etc.

I have tried to search what the ESLint rule for this is and can't seem to find it.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `messages`. I think it is a variable from useSate. Linter suggests adding messages to dependencies array. MB code bellow can help.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } form 'react';

const Component = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsub = db.collection('messages')
      .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          setMessages((prevMessages) => {
            const index = prevMessages.findIndex(({ id }) => id === doc.id);
            if (index !== -1) {
              return prevMessages;
            }
            
            return ([
              { id: doc.id, ...doc.data() },
              ...prevMessages,
            ]);
          });
        });
      });

    return unsub;
  }, []);
  
  return null;
};
```

Comment: So how will you unsubscribe with the listener?

Comment: I forgot about it. use `unsub`